# I need to disable chatter feed to appear on home page and any record page

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter, home-page-component, chatter-feed

I need to disable chatter feed to appear on home page and any record page. I have created VF page and used it in VF home page component but it is not working.

> Please find below VF page code.

```
    <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStyleSheets="false">
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function hideChatterFeed(){
        var isFeedShown =
            document
                    .getElementById('hideFeedLink')
                    .style
                    .display == 'none' ? false:true;

        if(isFeedShown && chatter){
            if(sfdcPage.entityId){
                chatter.getFeed().toggle(
                    '{"subjectId":"' + sfdcPage.entityId + '","feedType":"ENTITY"}'
                );
            }
            else{
                chatter.getFeed().toggle(
                    '{"subjectId":"","feedType":"NEWS"}'
                );           
            }
        }
    }

    document.onreadystatechange = hideChatterFeed;
</script>

 </head>

</apex:page>
```

[image]

Please Help in this.

Comment: Why not just disable it entirely at that point?

Comment: since to Install CPQ package we need to enable Chatter in Org but we do not want users to see Chatter

Answer (score 0):

As you already created a visualforce, try include on the style tags

```
 <style>
 .bPageTitle .metadata { display:none; }
 </style>
```

chatter component will remain internally although that tag will hide part where chatter is alocated on the Html.